# Android: выполнение вычислений в фоне

Tags: android, многопоточность, kotlin

Есть класс, работающий с неким ViewGroup. Он инстанцируется в Main-треде, вначале выполняет некоторые манипуляции с вьюхами (они должны в Main-треде выполняться), после чего начинает некоторые вычисления, связанные с запросами в базу, загрузкой файлов и т.п, по их окончании должен опять произвести некоторые изменения во вьюхах. Видимо, следует вычисления в середине вынести из main-треда.

- Как правильно выйти из main-треда и вернуться? Вижу AsyncTask, Service, InstentService, Timer.Schedule, в котлине ещё и корутины. Что из этого использовать?
- Насколько тяжёлые вычисления следует выносить? Насколько сами переключения между тредами в андройде тяжелы? Чтобы затраты на них не перекрыли выгоду.
- Что если у меня будет параллельно сотня подобных объектов, каждый из которых начнёт переключаться в другой тред? Не расплодяться ли треды, не начнуться ли от этого проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запуск нового потока из основного это не проблема. Как только новый поток закончит работу, он уничтожится.
Для сложных фоновых вычислений я использую след.запись:

```
// в основном потоке
Thread thread = new Thread(null, doBackgroundThreadProcessing,"Background");
thread.start();

private Runnable doBackgroundThreadProcessing = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        backgroundThreadProcessing();
    }
};

private void backgroundThreadProcessing() {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // здесь вычисления
        }
    };
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
}
```

или

```
Thread myThread_turn = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // работа
    }
});
myThread_turn.start(); // запускаем
```

Для обновления UI из потока использую

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Насколько тяжелые вычисления, решаете вы. Например работу с файлами, или интернетом, или устройствами, нужно выносить в отдельный поток. Если у вас вдруг появилась табличка "Приложение не отвечает", выносите расчеты в поток фоновый.
Переполнение памяти никто не отменял, так что старайтесь не плодить потоки